# AEM Query needed for property/nodename within component

Tags: aem, query-builder, crx

I tried to extract the pages which have the node fileReferance within component, I tried to use property.depth and also nodename for the same however, its not showing any results.

Please find below screenshot from CRX:

[image]

Can you please help me to generate the query for same.

Regards,
M

Comment: What's the query you tried?

Comment: I just tried below:

type=cq:Page
1_property=jcr:content/stage/*/branding/fileReference
1_property.value=/content/dam/bmw/common/images/submarkenlogo/*.png
1_property.operation=unequals
orderby=path
2_property=jcr:content/cq:lastReplicationAction
2_property.value=Activate
p.limit=-1

Comment: Now I am getting results, I am trying to fetch pages where 1_property.value=/content/dam/bmw/common/images/submarkenlogo/*.png should not equal however, its not showing me correct result, its showing me result which include this path